# Sturm-Liouville eigenvalues and the zeroes of a Bessel function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

### HINT ONLY PLEASE

I'm trying to show that the eigenvalues of the Sturm-Liouville problem

$xu''(x) + u'(x) + \lambda xu(x) = 0$

$0<x<1$

with $u(x)$ bounded as $x \to \infty$ and $u(1) = 0$, are $\lambda = j_n^2$, where the $j_n$, $n = 1,2,\dots$, are the zeroes of the Bessel Function:

$J_0(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^m\frac{x^{2m}}{2^{2m} (m!)^2} $

---

I see that the condition on $u(1)$ gives

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^m\frac{\lambda }{2^{2m} (m!)^2} = 0$

but this isn't quite what I want, even though it looks similar. Can someone please give me a hint as to which way to go with this?

Comment: Do a change of variables: $v(t)=u(t/k)$, where $k^2=\lambda$.

Answer (score 3):

Your guess about the Bessel function is correct. But, if you let me give you this piece of advice: forget about the sum.

Furthermore, the general solution for your problem is:

$$y(x) = A J_0(\xi \, x) + B Y_0(\xi \, x) $$

where $\xi^2 = \lambda$. The boundary conditions require $B$ to vanish since $Y(z)$ (second kind Bessel function of order $0$) is singular at $z\to 0$. The condition $y(1) = 0$ leads to:

$$0 = A J_0(\xi), $$

so $\xi$ must be a zero of the first kind Bessel function of order $0$. Set $\xi = \xi_n$ and your solution becomes:

$$y_n(x) = A_n J_0(\xi_n \, x) = J_0 (\xi_n \, x),$$

where I have set $A_n \to 1$ since the equation is homogeneous.

Cheers! and I hope this is useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe looking ar "Mathematical Methods for physicists" by Arfken and Weber, might help. Change the variable y=kx, and check for orthogonality.

I hope this is helpful.