# Bessel equation with boundary condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions

I've already asked a question about solving the equation $x y'' + y' +k x y=0$ and I was suggested to use Bessel equation by multiplying the equation by x. the answer is $a J 0(\sqrt{k} x) +b Y 0(\sqrt{k} x)$ ,now what if it had boundary condition like y(1)=0,how can we find the constants a and b?
Thanks.

Comment: you need another condition, maybe on $y'$.

Comment: Assume that $y(0)$ and $y' (0)$ are bounded and $0<x<1$.what now?

Comment: These are the only conditions of the question.

Comment: How can you have $y(0)$ if $x > 0$?

Comment: We don't have it,it has just said that it is bounded.

Comment: Well you know that $b =0$ due to the solution being bounded.

Comment: Very good point,then as $y(1)$ equals to 0 and a can't be zero,$J 0(\sqrt {k})$ must be zero,so the roots of the $J 0( \sqrt {x})$ are the eigenvalues and $a J 0(\sqrt {k} x)$ are eigenfunctions.Thanks.

Comment: What is the use of $y'(0)$ that is bounded?

Comment: Is what I mentioned in previous comments right?

Comment: I think this question will explain it better [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/334913/sturm-liouville-eigenvalues-and-the-zeroes-of-a-bessel-function)